# How to cross-tabulate two variables in R?

Tags: r, frequency

This seems to be basic, but I wont get it. I am trying to compute the frequency table in R for the data as below

```
1 2 
2 1 
3 1
```

I want to transport the the two way frequencies in csv output, whose rows will be all the unique entries in column A of the data and whose columns will be all the unique entries in column B of the data, and the cell values will be the number of times the values have occurred. I have explored some constructs like `table` but I am not able to output the values correctly in csv format.

Output of sample data:

```
"","1","2"
"1",0,1
"2",1,0
"3",1,0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "1 2 
2 1 
3 1")
```

Calculate frequencies using `table`:

(If your object is a matrix, you could convert it to a data frame using `as.data.frame` before using `table`.)

```
tab <- table(df)

   V2
V1  1 2
  1 0 1
  2 1 0
  3 1 0
```

Write data with the function `write.csv`:

```
write.csv(tab, "tab.csv")
```

The resulting file:

```
"","1","2"
"1",0,1
"2",1,0
"3",1,0
```